# Update jsonb field based on string value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field "formats" in "files" table that looks like this:

```
{
    "small": {
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "url": "https://my-digital-ocean-storage-1.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/strapi/d30cfee509a8748029f41a690e52ea3c.jpg",
        "hash": "d30cfee509a8748029f41a690e52ea3c",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "name": "small_nowe_1.jpg",
        "path": null,
        "size": 50.15,
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "thumbnail": {
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "url": "https://my-digital-ocean-storage-1.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/strapi/0b2bb902b3da82b1254dfbe873a650c8.jpg",
        "hash": "0b2bb902b3da82b1254dfbe873a650c8",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "name": "thumbnail_nowe_1.jpg",
        "path": null,
        "size": 7.28,
        "width": 156,
        "height": 156
    }
}
```

what i want is that i want to update this jsonb field and change "url" for example from  `"https://my-digital-ocean-storage-1.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/strapi/d30cfee509a8748029f41a690e52ea3c.jpg"` to `"https://my-digital-ocean-storage-2.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/strapi/d30cfee509a8748029f41a690e52ea3c.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jsonb-function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) jsonb_set() for this:

```
    UPDATE files
    SET formats = jsonb_set(formats -- current content
      , '{small,url}' -- path
      , to_jsonb(replace( formats->'small'->>'url', '1.fra1', '2.fra1.cdn'))) -- new content
    WHERE id = 123;
```

Comment: What is your doing is updating all records with static value but i want to update records based on values that are already provided. For example: https://my-digital-ocean-storage-1.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/strapi/d30cfee509a8748029f41a690e52ea3c.jpg

so i basically want to replace https://my-digital-ocean-storage-1.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com to https://my-digital-ocean-storage-2.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com

Comment: @Viktor So basically `1.fra1` should become `2.fra1.cdn`.

Comment: Yes i want from 1.fra1 to 2.fra1.cdn

Comment: @Viktor See the updated answer, using replace()